# T4 Runtime text templates in a nuget package

Tags: nuget, t4

I have a project with a runtime text template, i want to be able to call

```
mytemplate.TransformCode();
```

from a different project. I only need access to the mytemplate.cs file it generates and do not want to edit the template in the second project.

I have included the .tt file in the nuget package of the first project and installed the nuget package on the second.

The problem is the actual .tt file is installed into the second project, and then fails to compile due to the assembly reference

```
<#@ assembly name="$(SolutionDir)\..\..\bin\LanguageExt.Core.dll" #>
```

Because they relative path to the assembly is no longer correct.
So I need a way to either suppress installation of the tt file into the second project, and be able to instantiate the mytemplate class file from the dll and call GenerateText()

If that's not possible I'd like to at least be able to use a parameter for the assembly relative path, so I can make sure it builds in both places.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Right, it's as simple as setting 'Build Action' to 'None' on the tt file
*gets coat*